# Android - printing CharSequence[]

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

This returns a null pointer.  `array[0].toString()` does as well.  What am I doing wrong?

```
final CharSequence[] array = res.getTextArray(R.array.arrayOfThings);
System.out.println("array pos 0: " + array[0]);
```

...

```
<array name="arrayOfThings">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/robolectric/browse_thread/thread/10ebba24c80e9edf?pli=1), you could try using getStringArray() instead of getTextArray() when dealing with resource array printing. See if that fixes your problem.

Comment: getStringArray() returns the string array, what can i do if i need charsequence array if i do not use getTextArray()